# how to getText of the labels inside a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 labels inside a panel , I want to get there texts how can I do that ?

```
    JPanel pn = new JPanel();
    pn.add(new JLabel("Kurdish"));
    pn.add(new JLabel("Arabic"));
    pn.add(new JLabel("English"));

    System.out.println(pn.getComponent(1).getName());// it is null ? Arabic ..
    System.out.println(pn.getComponent(1)); // gives me all details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `Component` to a `JLabel` before you can invoke the `getText()` method:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)pn.getComponent(1);
System.out.println( label.getText() );
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ❤
 
 System.out.println(((JLabel)pn.getComponent(0)).getText());

Answer (score 1):

use `getText()`:

```
System.out.println(((JLabel)pn.getComponent(1)).getText());
```

Comment: I did it but there is no getText method ! , there is getText method for label .

Comment: sorry cast it to jlabel before